# R - bubble graphs for survey data

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2

I have a graph that looks like this.

[image]
I like the vertical layout. However, instead of bars I'd like to create bubbles using the following data. The `PCI` is the size of the bubble around the `Mean` value.

```
                                                PCI     Mean
Human adaptation to carnivores                  0.07    3.37
Acceptance of some human-carnivore conflict     0.31    2.10
Enforcement and monitoring of the rule of law   0.05    3.28
Locals' acceptance of management authority      0.03    3.46
Carnivore adaptation to humans                  0.06    3.12
Permitting regulated hunting of carnivores      0.39    1.95
Prohibiting any killing of carnivores           0.34    1.46
```

Not sure how to do this in R or ggplot.

Comment: I guess `ggplot(df, aes(x=item, y=Mean, ymin=Mean-PCI, ymax=Mean+PCI)) + geom_pointrange()` would give you "bubbles".

Comment: That helps! I slightly modified it to `ggplot(df, aes(x=Mean, y=item, , xmin=1, xmax=5,size=PCI)) + geom_point()` and that looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Based on help from @lukeA I used `ggplot(df, aes(x=Mean, y=item, , xmin=1, xmax=5,size=PCI)) + geom_point()`and that did the trick.